# Bootstrap 4 Modal and jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello I am having the following issue. I have recently upgraded Bootstrap to version 4.1 (from 3.3.X) and I am trying to make modals behave in the same way they used to.

I am having a standard bootstrap Modal box within a page

```
<!-- language:all lang-html -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">   
  <div class="modal-dialog">     
    <div class="modal-content">       
      <div class="modal-header modal-header-success">         
        <h1 class="modal-title"></h1>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>       
      </div>       
      <div class="modal-body">
        //Some code that contains jquery-ui DatePickers and Tooltips with absolute position
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want this box to have a maximum height that is almost equal to viewport height and if necessary have an internal scrollbar for y in case the content is taller. I therefore added the following css.

***css:***
    #myModal .modal-body { max-height: calc(100vh - 200px); overflow-y: auto; }

Inside the modal-body there are some DatePickers that use jquery-ui and basic tooltips with absolute position divs that appear on mouse over.

**The Problem:**
Both the datepickers and the tooltips when they show (if they are near the border), they go "under" the modal-backdrop and cause scrollbar for x which is not wanted. In the previous version of bootstrap the same code behaved differently and both the tooltips and datepickers (with appropiate z-index) appeared on top of the backdrop (when needed)

I am looking for a potential workaround to achieve the same behavior with bootstrap-4 that I used to have with bootstrap-3. I understand that part of the problem comes from the stacking context associated with the display flex. Playing with the z-index value has no effect and also trying to force an overflow-x:visible; did not have the desired results.

I could try to avoid scenarios where these elements go near the border, but I would like to know if there is a workaround.

I also made an example in Fiddle to demonstrate the problem. It shows a simple hovering tooltip, but the behavior is the same with the datepickers as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/psarag/g7dr1tcs/46/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

use this style for span tag:

```
display: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 212);
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
```

It will look like this: [image]